# What is the difference in the usage and meaning of ‘prohibit’ and ‘bar’？

Tags: word-usage, verbs, differences

Is there any difference between ‘prohibit’ and ‘bar’ when the two words are used to express the meaning ‘to stop officially from doing sth’?

Comment: Please tell us what you understood when you looked these words up in a dictionary.

Comment: ***Banned*** is far more likely than ***prohibited*** to be used with the specific subsense [of a person] *not allowed **to be present*** - as opposed to [of an action] *not allowed **to be done***. Both words are fine with *Smoking is **banned / prohibited** in / by the pub*, but *My alcoholic neighbour is **prohibited** in / by the pub* doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

'**Ban**' is normally the action of forbidding something by *the law* or *a social rule*. As I believe, the best synonym of this word would be '**censor**'.

'**Prohibit**' is a verb very similar to '**forbid**'. They mean the same, yet the former sounds more *official* and might also come with some *law enforced penalties*.

The main difference between '**bar**' and '**ban**' is that the latter usually applies to *things*, and the former usually applies to *people*.

Comment: The question is asking about _bar_, not _ban_ (though I’d support keeping _ban_ in the answer as well, since it’s obviously another closely related verb).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, sorry for that little mistake of mine. Added some information about '**bar**'.

Comment: I would normally say that the meaning of **bar** and **ban** is the reverse of what you claim. *I barred the door* (*bar* applies to things) versus *I banned her from talking* (*ban* applies to people). Of course, they can be used interchangeably in some contexts—but not in others. Or maybe you confused which word was the *former* and which word was the *latter* in your sentence. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford, no, I did *not* confused *the latter* and *the former*. Actually, it appears we are both right in some way. (I did some research and found https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bar_2). Yet https://grammarist.com/usage/ban-bar/ supports my way of understanding the difference between the words.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary 'bar' and 'prohibit' are synonyms:

***BAR***

// Prevent or
prohibit
(someone) from
doing something
or from going
somewhere.

‘journalists had been barred from covering the elections’

***PROHIBIT***

// Formally forbid someone from doing something.

‘he is prohibited from becoming a director'.

As we see from this '***PROHIBIT***' is more formal than '***BAR***'.